One-way speed of light and the luminiferous aether
The "luminiferous aether" hypothesis is famously falsified by the Michelson-Morley experiment. It is explained that if there is an aether and we move through it, then there will be an "aether wind" which would cause effects on the speed of light depending on direction. Since the experiment found no directionally dependent effects on the speed of light, there is no aether wind and no aether.
But it is known to be impossible in principle to measure the one-way speed of light. And indeed the Michelson-Morley Experiment measures light that has taken a round trip. In a round trip traversal any variance due to one direction is canceled out by having to traverse exactly the opposite direction in exactly the same quantity.
So then how could the Michelson-Morley experiment have found any other result? If there were an aether and an aether wind, why would we not expect this result anyway because the return trip of the light cancels any effect of the trip out?

The return trip does not cancels any effect of the trip.
Even if it could be arguable for light traveling a path exactly parallel to the aether wind, it is not true for the arm perpendicular to the wind.
The aether wind would imply an increment in perpendicular velocity of the light signal, implying it would travel a triangular-shape trajectory going and back, not a straight line. I think a good analogy could be a boat crossing a river with a strong current. If the boat go on the other side and back, the current will carry the boat to its direction, changing the trajectory.
Despite that, it seems that Michelson and his team tried to detect Aether Wind in a lot of directions, and to rotate the interferometer brought no difference in the negative result. It is important to emphasize, however, that their experiment of 1886 carried to estimate the effect of motion of other medium, like water and air, for example, and for these media the difference is detectable, following Fizeau experiment and previsions made by Fresnel years before. It is worth to read it.
I recommend you to read the Feynman explanation of the experiment here.


In a round trip traversal any variance due to one direction is
canceled out by having to traverse exactly the opposite direction in
exactly the same quantity.

That is not correct. Consider an airplane traveling at a constant speed $v$ a distance $d$ in one direction then turning around and coming back.
Case A: There is no wind. The duration of the outbound trip is $d/v$, the same for the return trip. The time for the round trip is $2d/v$.
Case B: There is wind in the same direction as the traveling plane with a wind speed of $v$. The airplane travels relative to the wind, so the total speed relative to the ground is $v+v=2v$. The duration of the outbound trip is shorter with a duration of $d/2v$. The return ground speed is $v-v=0$, so the return time is $d/0=\infty$. The the round trip time is infinite and the plane never makes it back.
If your logic were right, the duration in Case A and B should be the same. But instead, by choosing a wind speed between $0$ and $v$, you can make the round trip time any number between the original duration and infinity.

There is no physical reason for $c$ to be anisotropic, i.e. moving at different speeds in different directions. If it were anyway, you could draw an isomorphism from all events/processes in an anisotropic-$c$ universe to equivalent ones in an isotropic-$c$ universe, so there is functionally no difference between anisotropic-$c$ universes and isotropic-$c$ universes. Thus there's no issue with MM's results.
The other important thing to note is that the luminiferous aether is completely obsolete in modern quantum field theories and relativistic models of the Universe. Consider the following:

Light, i.e. photons, i.e. excitations of the electromagnetic field at the QFT level, do not require any medium to propagate. The EM field permeates the entire Universe, and light as it is understood in modern times needs only the existence of an EM field to propagate, making the luminiferous aether obsolete.
If the luminiferous aether existed, the most important postulate of relativity would be violated: if there is an underlying medium through which light travels, then moving at great speed in any one direction would make $c$ appear to be anisotropic. The most important postulate is that $c$ is always measured to be the same in all directions, since that means that physics does not care about what your velocity is (which it has been observed not to). If there were a luminiferous aether, then the apparent value of $c$ would depend on your state of motion, which has not been observed.
Both of these facts come into play in a way that can certainly not be denied because it is a concrete thing that, at the time of this writing, is still on operation: the Large Hadron Collider. The LHC accelerates particles to very nearly lightspeed; if the luminiferous aether existed, not only would electromagnetic interactions between these particles be markedly different from what is observed, but there would be no reason for the limiting velocity of these particles to be $c$.

So MM's results make perfect sense: they did not observe the existence of a luminiferous aether, which is exactly what modern QM and SR/GR now tell us. The existence of a luminiferous aether, or equivalently the invalidity of relativity, would mean that there would be no reason for physics to be Lorentz-symmetric, and our best observations and theories of the Universe point to everything being Lorentz-symmetric: the local result of an experiment does not depend on your position or velocity or rotation relative to anything.

The question itself proceeds from a mistake.
The Michelson-Morley Experiment in 1887 didn't falsify the luminiferous aether, and it was not conceived in the first place so as to test for the presence of a medium or not. Rather it was conceived to test how quickly we were moving in that medium (since geocentrism in which everything moves around the stationary Earth had already been thrown into discredit by then).
The presence of a medium was already assumed, because by that time physics had a reasonable understanding of how other wave mediums worked, and it could be seen that light worked in a similar manner. Diffraction gratings had been known for centuries by then, for example.
The unexpected null result of the MM experiment simply had no principled explanation at the time. It was not thought by anybody to suggest the absence of a wave medium, since the involvement of a wave medium was already fairly obvious from other facts. If anything, support for geocentrism was probably the worst fear about what the experiment had shown.
Amongst physicists though, the question was about how exactly this wave medium worked and how the experimental evidence was reconciled.
Research continued, and ultimately the systematic aspects were recognised and modelled as additional terms, but with no principled explanation for why these terms should be present. For example, there was no principled physical explanation for why objects should "length contract" when translating through the medium.
Einstein apparently proceeded on the question from a different direction in the formulation of SR, not searching for evidence of the aether nor intending to rebut its existence, but instead apparently accepting that if absolute motion were not detectable then the situation must logically be fully symmetrical no matter who is moving. A nice geometrical solution resulted from that reasoning.
Philosophical disputes ensued, particularly between Einstein and Lorentz, and at their conclusion, aether was not declared falsified at all, but as consistent with the available evidence as any alternative view.

But it is known to be impossible in principle to measure the one-way speed of light.
If there were an aether and an aether wind, why would we not expect this result anyway because the return trip of the light cancels any effect of the trip out?

Because that fact was not properly understood or widely acknowledged until the early 20th century, probably some 30 years after the Michelson-Morley experiment, once Einstein and Lorentz had duked it out.
